# How to create a cocoa touch framework file abc .framework that included multiple other parties header and .frameworks files internally used

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoapods, xmppframework, cocoa-touch

How to create a cocoa touch framework file abc .framework that included multiple other parties header and .frameworks files internally used.

I am trying to build my custom framework for drag and drop to the tech-clients.

All they need to do is to use my framework for the purpose mentioned in their app and internally my framework will import inside all other 3rd party frameworks like CocoaPods libraries, assets, .frameworks,etc.

How can I achieve it. Tried this this point for more clarification

I tried to make a custom framework build -- SUCCESS
Used PodFile to add other library pods -- SUCCESS
Build the Library again by opening Workspace -- SUCCESS
Create an aggregate target to make this framework universal -- FAILED due to errors that the other pods related files are not found in my framework - FAILURE.

Any one can guide more what wrong I may be doing.

Comment: have you added the 3rd party frameworks in embeddedd framework secction ?

Comment: I want to create my own "messageservice.framework" which have all the information inside it. However the message service needs XMPPframework and other Dependancy framework . Hence to avoid that exposing outside I need to put it inside my framework project. I have used Cocoapods so my pod file is as below.

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

#Pods XMPP Framework
pod 'XMPPFramework'
#use_frameworks!

Now my problem is all the framework files and ".a" generated in this Pods are coming outside my "mesaging.framework" file, How to keep all in one place ?

Comment: So I can just pass the "messaging.framework" as final deliverable to my clients without exposing source code and internal libraries used.